# What are Jhipster Roles used for?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster. I wanted to know if anyone can explain to me what Jhipster Roles are used for? Do they give certain users extra permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles/authorities are defined by Spring Security to specify what a user is authorized to do, please read their [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authz-arch.html).

Authorities are then exposed to JHipster Angular's code as state data as explained [here](https://jhipster.github.io/using-angularjs/#authorizations) which can be used to prevent transition to a state or to hide/show some part of the views using has-authority and has-any-authority directives.